# Syntax error when intalling pyneurgen - invalid syntax

Tags: python, powershell, installation

I am new in Python and trying to install PyNeurGen library in windows 10
Invoking easy_install pyneurgen in powershell I see:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3.5\lib\site-packages\pyneurgen-0.3.1-py3.5.egg\pyneurgen\neuralnet.py", line 613
    print "sample: %s errors: %s" % (
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I invoke the installation again I see:

```
Best match: pyneurgen 0.3.1
Processing pyneurgen-0.3.1-py3.5.egg
pyneurgen 0.3.1 is already the active version in

Using c:\program files\anaconda3.5\lib\site-packa
Processing dependencies for pyneurgen
Finished processing dependencies for pyneurgen
```

When I run a simple script using PyNeurGen I see in PyCharm the same error:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 533, in spec_from_file_location
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3.5\lib\site-packages\pyneurgen-0.3.1-py3.5.egg\pyneurgen\neuralnet.py", line 613
    print "sample: %s errors: %s" % (
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestions how to solve the problem?

Comment: you need to use python2

Comment: `print "hello"` is python 2 syntax. It's a shame the library was not ported 2 python 3, but their last release was 5 years ago, so maybe not that strange.

Comment: The issue is with respect to the source code. when you open the source code by clicking on the which shows where the error has occurred. You will find that the syntax for the print function is wrong. once you rectify it, the code will work as usual.